# how to slice a json array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I want to slice the the json array in Angular which looks like this below.[image]

And the code is below

```
export class AppComponent {
  color: string = 'green';
  public stocklist = [];
  public objectKeys = Object.keys;
  constructor() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/stocks';
    axios.get(url).then(res =>{
      this.stocklist = res.data.result[0].slice(0,10);
      console.log(this.stocklist);
    })
  }
}
```

But it always shows res.data.result[0].slice is not a function, but we can see res.data.result[0] is literally a json array which can iterate in using *ngFor.

So which shold i use for slicing the json arry.

Comment: They are objects with integers as key. Not arrays

Comment: so how could i turn into array

Comment: Please dont use `axios` in angular, change to `httpClient`

Comment: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) or [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) should do the trick

Comment: @OwenKelvin  I used it  in Vue, so I thought it gone works too in angular,   however i will check the angular doc later about httpclient  thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Kainingxin in Angular it is good practice to use `Observable`. As you may notice, axios returns a Promise, Have a look at `Observables` as `httpClient` returns an `Observable ` and not `Promise `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is the method of the `Array`, but you are calling it for the object.

Use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to make it to array.

```
export class AppComponent {
  color: string = 'green';
  public stocklist = [];
  public objectKeys = Object.keys;
  constructor() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/stocks';
    axios.get(url).then(res =>{
      this.stocklist = Object.values(res.data.result[0]).slice(0,10);
      console.log(this.stocklist);
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @WilliamWang solution implementing `Observables`

```typescript
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  color: string = 'green';
  public stocklist = [];
  public objectKeys = Object.keys;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/stocks';
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(res => {
      this.stocklist = Object.values(res.data.result[0]).slice(0,10);
      console.log(this.stocklist);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition, I just learned to use httpclient instead of axios to execute http request. And at first, I wrote just like you did but it alerted that there were not exist ''data'' attribute for 'res', so in considering the data structure of the val stored in Observable, I had to identify the Observable with an interface so that I could get access to the data inside the observable object.